# Не выводится сниппет AjaxForm

Tags: modx, revo

Здравствуйте.
Помогите пожалуйста советом, так как всё перерыл в сети информацию по данной теме. (На modx вообще скупая информация с интернете, в плане тонкостей и проблем) Помещаю этот код в шаблон, пробуя вызвать чанк через сниппет вышесказанный и он не появляется на странице. Хотя вызывая его напрямую он является на свет:

```
    &snippet=`FormIt`
                &form=`ajaxForm`
                &emailTpl=`email_tpl`
                &hooks=`email`
                &emailSubject=`Lear Corporation`
                &emailTo=`niceclient@yandex.ru`
                &emailFrom=`tornado@kalugainfo.ru`
                &validate=`name:minLenght=^3^,email:email:required,message:required`
                &validationErrorMessage=`В форме содержатся ошибки!`
                &successMessage=`Сообщение успешно отправлено`
            ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

AjaxForm это "обертка" для других сниппетов, в данном случае FormIt. Убедитесь что оба дополнения установлены, а чанк ajaxForm существует и содержит html форму.

Корректный вызов AjaxForm для работы с FormIt:

```
[[!AjaxForm?
&snippet=`FormIt`
&form=`ajaxForm`
&emailTpl=`email_tpl`
&hooks=`email`
&emailSubject=`Lear Corporation`
&emailTo=`niceclient@yandex.ru`
&emailFrom=`tornado@kalugainfo.ru`
&validate=`name:minLenght=^3^,email:email:required,message:required`
&validationErrorMessage=`В форме содержатся ошибки!`
&successMessage=`Сообщение успешно отправлено`
]]
```